# Fetching CloudKit User Record using UserRecordID

Tags: ios, iphone, database, swift, cloudkit

The question is to fetch data from User Records when UserRecordID is fetched.

Method to get User ID:
    post.creatorUserRecordID?.recordName

My Users Record Type contains columns like username, so, I need to parse them for a concrete user. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question and you already have a CKRecordID. All you got to do then is to fetchRecordWithID using this CKRecordID you got.

```
let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
publicDatabase.fetchRecordWithID(recordId, completionHandler: { (fetchRecord: CKRecord?, fetchError: NSError?) in
    if let error = fetchError
    {
        // error getting user record, try again
        print("-> cloudKitFetchUserRecord - error fetching user record - Error \(error)")
    }
    else
    {
        if let record = fetchRecord
        {
            if record.recordType == CKRecordTypeUserRecord
            {
                // valid record
                print("-> cloudKitFetchUserRecord - fetching user record - valid record found - \(record.recordID.recordName))")

               // unwrap your values - on your case username
               if let object = record.objectForKey("username") as? Bool
                {
                    // do something with object
                }

            }
            else
            {
                // not valid record
                print("-> cloudKitFetchUserRecord - fetching user record - The record that came back is not a CKRecordTypeUserRecord")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // record nil
            print("-> cloudKitFetchUserRecord - fetching user record - fetch record returned nil")
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler now using async/await in Swift 5

```
func getUserID() async {
    
    let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.XXX.XXXX")
    // CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase // or default public container
    
    do {
        let userRecordID = try await container.userRecordID()
        print("recordName: \(userRecordID.recordName)")
    }
    catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
```